# How to make action on node.js server after button click using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have a problem. I want to make server do something after clicking on button.
This is my HTML code:

```
    <input name="like" id="like" value="Like" type="submit" />
    <script>
        $('like').click(function(){
            $.post('/test')
        });
    </script>
```

and this is my server-side code:

```
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

And it doesn't work.

Comment: it should be saying something ?

Comment: Well, what do you expect?

Comment: can it be `$('#like').click(function(){` instead of `$('like').click(function(){`

Comment: Thanks prava I missed # :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is here, you have forgotten the `#` for targeting element by id, so click would never be invoke.

```
$('#like').click(function(){
    $.post('/test');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you aren't selecting the input tag correctly. If you want to select a DOM element by ID, you'll want to use '#IDname' as your selector.

For this example, that means changing it to

```
...
$('#like').click(function(){
...
```

This also might not fix the error entirely: using a an input field with a type of "submit", you will likely have to do something like this:

```
...
$('#like').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
...
```

to keep the default submit event on the input from "bubbling up."